# zxing node-red-contrib-qrcode-generator - issues with Wi-Fi QR code

Tags: zxing

If I create a QR code in Node Red for Open Wi-Fi network it works fine i.e. I paste the resulting msg.payload content into browser, scan it with my iPhone (iOS 14.2) and it brings up request to to join the specified Wi-Fi network.
If in the node I hard-code encryption = WPA, SSID = MySSID and Password = abcd12345 (also tried "abcd12345") when I paste msg.payload into my browser I always get error "might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_INVALID_URL".
I had a bit more success injecting a string (WIFI:T:WPA;S:myWiFi;P:abcd12345;;) into the node in that it creates a QR code, but when I scan it then iPhone shows "No usable data found". I tried with "" around S and P options too.
Any ideas?...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, missed in the nodes guide that it requires msg.qrcodeinput as the input, not msg.payload! Changed that and now it works.